# Create WCF Service signature same as internal non-dot net service signature

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, webmethod

I need to create a WCF Service, which will internally consume another non-dot net webservice. The main purpose is to abstract this webservice from the outside world. Hence for a transparent call, I need the IO signature of my WCF service same as that of my Internal Service.

I have added the internal service as a Web Service Reference in my project. I am able to create a client and also call it. But I am somehow unable to expose the datatypes needed by the internal webservices as part of my WCF Service.

The architecture here is going to be like:

Client <--> ComplexTypeResponse response MyWCFService.processData(ComplexTypeRequest request) <--> ComplexTypeResponse response MyInternalService.processData(ComplexTypeRequest request)

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why add a WCF service as an added layer. you are going to simply degrade the performance of your client app as it will need to go through 2 hops before reaching the actual service

Comment: IF you still want do call add the hop, it might be due to the way your  service reference (reference.cs). can you post the code of ComplexTypeResponse  and your WCF service

Comment: It is basically External Client <--> MyWCFService <--> MyInternalService